# Horizontal layout of patches in legend (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I create legend in my chart this way:

```
legend_handles.append(matplotlib.patches.Patch(color=color1, label='group1'))
legend_handles.append(matplotlib.patches.Patch(color=color2, label='group2'))
ax.legend(loc='upper center', handles=legend_handles, fontsize='small')
```

This results in the legend items stacked vertically (top-bottom), while I would like to put them horizontally left to right.

How can I do that?

(`matplotlib` v1.4.3)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is an argument determining the number of columns `ncol=`.

```
ax.legend(loc='upper center', handles=legend_handles, fontsize='small', ncol=2)
```

This should do the trick. Got it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737681/fill-the-right-column-of-a-matplotlib-legend-first?rq=1) thread.