# Variable length columns in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way/example to have multiple columns in a legend in a matplotlib plot with different number of rows in each column?

Comment: Yes, you can make empty entries to fill the shorter column and be explicit about which plotted line goes in which order. See this (different spacing, is adaptable): https://stackoverflow.com/a/21571063/1168043

Comment: Please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737681/fill-the-right-column-of-a-matplotlib-legend-first). I would consider it to be duplicate, since the idea is the same: Use "empty" artists to fill columns on the left. If there is a problem with implementation you may edit your question to include the code you have problems with and we can reopen the question.